# Finding the general solution to a second-order linear ODE: $y''+y'-2y=1+e^{-2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following:

1) $y''+y'-2y=1+e^{-2x}$

result should be

$c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 e^{x} - \frac13 e^{-2x} x - \frac12 $

while I can find easily the general solution ($c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 e^{x}$)
I can't understand why the particular solution is $- \frac13 e^{-2x} x - \frac12 $

from what I know about those equations, the particular solution should be in the form of

$y(x) = axe^{-2x}$

composed by only 1 piece, while the solution above seems like 2 pieces

and so, trying to solve I get:

$y'(x) = ae^{-2x}(-2x+1)$

$y''(x) = axe^{-2x}(4x-4)$

then, substituting those on 1) I get, after some cleanup

$axe^{-2x}(-3) =  1 + e^{-2x}$

and if I did it right, $ a = -\frac 23$

so the particular solution that I get is $y(x) = -\frac 23 xe^{-2x}$

what am I doing wrong?
sorry for my english and my bad formatting (this is the first time here)

Comment: The particular solution for the $e^{-2x}$ is of the form $c_3 xe^{-2x}$ (since $-2$ is a single root of the characteristic polynomial). The particular solution for the $1$ is of the form $c_4$ (since $0$ is not a root of the characteristic polynomial). So you should have the two together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note that the particular solution to your ODE will be the sum of the particular solutions to $y''+y'-2y=1$ and $y''+y'-2y=e^{-2x}$.

It is well-known that the particular solution to the first one is $y_p=A$ and the second one is $y_p=x(Be^{-2x})$. Note that the second one was multiplied by $x$ since $e^{-2x}$ is already in the complementary solution. Hence, you should be considering the following ansatz:
$$y_p(x)=A+Bxe^{-2x}$$

---

It is now easy to evaluate the values of $A$ and $B$:
$$y'_p(x)=Be^{-2x}-2Bxe^{-2x}$$
$$y''_p(x)=-4Be^{-2x}+4Bxe^{2x}$$
Substituting into your ODE gives:
$$(-4Be^{-2x}+4Bxe^{2x})+(Be^{-2x}-2Bxe^{-2x})-2(A+Bxe^{-2x})=1+e^{-2x}$$
$$\color{green}{-2A}\color{blue}{-3Be^{-2x}}=\color{green}{1}\color{blue}{+e^{-2x}}$$
Now equate coefficients of $1$ and $e^{-2x}$ (As shown in $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$), and the result follows.